# How to find slimes in minecraft 1.10.2 without cheating or external tools

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been looking for slimes for some time now and I don't seem to find any in the large room I built. I need to know how to easily find them without "cheating" whether they are in swamps or just underground

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slimes spawn in the Overworld in specific chunks below layer 40 regardless of light levels. They can also spawn in swamp biomes between layers 50 and 70 in light levels of 7 or less.